# Scrolling page in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

How can I manually scroll to the bottom (or top) of a page with the `RSelenium` WebDriver?  I have an element that only becomes available when it is visible on the page.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Assuming you got

```
library(RSelenium)
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$setWindowSize(width = 800, height = 300)
remDr$navigate("https://www.r-project.org/about.html")
```

You could scroll to the buttom like this:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
```

And you could scroll to the top like this:

```
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "home"))
```

---

And in case you want to scroll down just a bit, use

```
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "down_arrow"))
```

The names of the keys are in `selKeys`.