# Page Scrolling Using RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

I understand how to sendKeysToElement() if you need RSelenium to scroll to the Top or Bottom of a web page based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901072/scrolling-page-in-rselenium).

However, does anyone know how to scroll down a page in order to expose elements which are neither located at the top or bottom but somewhere in the middle of the page?

Comment: Make a guess. How would you do it manually in your browser, if you had no mouse?

Comment: Of course, thank you!