# Scroll down button in Selenium

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

Is there any easy / automated way to scroll down in a page using `RSelenium`?

I use a delay in a page in which I should scroll down to see the content.

```
remDr$navigate("http://www.pageyouprefer.com/")
Sys.sleep(35)
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901072/scrolling-page-in-rselenium and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251014/page-scrolling-using-rselenium

Comment: @lukeA thank you. There is no answer in this post so I asked it.

Comment: I thought it was obvious, but maybe it was not - my fault. I edited the [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901072/scrolling-page-in-rselenium).

Comment: Perhaps you tell us how much you want to scroll down  apart from minimum movement, page, top or end (since this has already been answered - see the first link of lukeA).

Comment: @R Yoda the page I try to scroll down is a page in which when I scroll down new content appears and it needs more scroll down to see additional new content until to finish. I tried to find something in the source code but I didn't.

Comment: @Berbery then scroll down in loop until you reach the bottom of page.

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll by javascript execute.

**Try this one.**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)", "");
```