# RSelenium: Scroll down to load web content

Tags: javascript, css, r, selenium, rselenium

I tried the code in here
[Scrolling page in RSelenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901072/scrolling-page-in-rselenium)
but it's not working as the web site that I'm working on will load more content as you scroll down. For example

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
webElem$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

This is the screenshot of part of the website.
[image]

Then I repeat the process again.

```
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
webElem$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

[image]

The result is still the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If unfortunately your code does not work for scrolling down, try using `executeScript()` as below :-

```
remDr$executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Comment: As a side note for people still facing trouble: using the `args = list(...)` input of `$executeScript` might be a problem solver.