# Scrolling through entire page with Rselenium, then extracting a tabular data into a data frame

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am currently trying to scrape a website with a combination of `Rselenium`,`rvest`, and the `tidyverse`.

The goal is to go to this [this website](https://www.pricecharting.com/category/pokemon-cards), click on one of the links (for instance, "Promo"), and then extract the entire table of data (e.g., card, and graded prices) using `rvest`.

I was able to get the table extracted without too much of an issue using the following code:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

pokemon <- read_html("https://www.pricecharting.com/console/pokemon-promo")

price_table <- pokemon %>% 
  html_elements("#games_table") %>% 
  html_table()
```

However, this has a couple of issues: 1) I cannot go through all the different card sets on the inital website link I provided (https://www.pricecharting.com/category/pokemon-cards), and  2) I cannot extract the entire table with this method - only what is primarly loaded.

To mitigate these issues I was looking into `Rselenium`. What I decided to do was go to the intial website, click on the link to a card set (e.g. "Promo"), and then load the entire page. This workflow can be shown here:

```
## open driver
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

## navigate to primary page
remDr$navigate("https://www.pricecharting.com/category/pokemon-cards")

## click on the link I want
remDr$findElement(using = "link text", "Promo")$clickElement()

## find the table
table <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "games_table")

## load the entire table
table$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))

## get the entire source
full_table <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

## read in the table
html_page <- read_html(full_table)


## Do the `rvest` technique I had above.
html_page %>% 
  html_elements("#games_table") %>% 
  html_table()
```

However, my issue is that I am once again getting the same 51 elements instead of the entire table.

I am wondering if it is possible to combine my two techniques, and where in my coding process this is going wrong.

Comment: The entire page is not loading, try to scroll to the bottom before extracting table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrolling page in RSelenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901072/scrolling-page-in-rselenium)

Comment: No I was using something similar in my initial posting. [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817315/rselenium-scroll-down-to-load-web-content?rq=1) ended up helping the issue. However, there was still the problem of the cursor being in the search bar so I had to "click" out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue. There were two things that were going on. The first is that the page was automatically loading with the cursor inside of a search bar. I got rid of this by doing `remDr$findElement(using = "css", "body")$clickElement()` to click into the body of the text. Next, as one [great question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817315/rselenium-scroll-down-to-load-web-content?rq=1) pointed out, if the scrolling/arrow keys are not working with  `sendKeysToElement(list(key = "up_arrow"))`, you should try `remDr$executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")`.

Hence, the a small sample of my script is the following:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

## opens the driver
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

link_texts <- c("Base Set", "Promo", "Fossil")
## navigates to the correct page
remDr$navigate("https://www.pricecharting.com/category/pokemon-cards")

for (name in link_texts) {
  ## finds the link and clicks on it
  remDr$findElement(using = "link text", name)$clickElement()
  ## gets the table path
  remDr$findElement(using = "css", "body")$clickElement()
  ## finds the table - this line may be extraneous
  table <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "body")
  ## scrolls to the bottom of the table
  remDr$executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
  Sys.sleep(1)
  remDr$executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
  Sys.sleep(1)
  remDr$executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
  Sys.sleep(1)
  remDr$executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
  Sys.sleep(1)
  remDr$executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
  Sys.sleep(1)
  remDr$executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
  Sys.sleep(1)
  ## get the entire page source that's been loaded
  html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
  ## read in the page source
  page <- read_html(html)
  
  data_name <- str_to_lower(str_replace(name, " ","_"))
  ## extract the tabular table
  df <- page %>% 
    html_elements("#games_table") %>% 
    html_table() %>% 
    pluck(1) %>% 
    select(1:4)
  assign(data_name, df)
  Sys.sleep(3)
  remDr$navigate("https://www.pricecharting.com/category/pokemon-cards")
}

## close driver
remDr$close()
rD$server$stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The page wasn't scrolling down as the cursor by default is in search bar. So did a little modification to your code so it scrolls down completely.

```
#Launch browser
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=9545L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://www.pricecharting.com/category/pokemon-cards")
remDr$findElement(using = "link text", "Promo")$clickElement()

#clicking outside the search bar
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", value = '//*[@id="console-page"]')$clickElement()

webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
#looping to get at the end of the page. 
for (i in 1:25){
  Sys.sleep(1)
  webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
} 

#extract table
full_table <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
html_page <- read_html(full_table)
html_page %>% 
  html_elements("#games_table") %>% 
  html_table()
[[1]]
# A tibble: 888 x 5
   Card                 Ungraded `Grade 9` `PSA 10`  ``                                                                                                        
   <chr>                <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>                                                                                                     
 1 Mew #8               $3.99    $38.79    $75.62    "+ Collection\n                                        In One Click\n                                    ~
 2 Mewtwo #3            $8.28    $65.91    $227.50   "+ Collection\n                                        In One Click\n                                    ~
 3 Charizard GX #SM211  $7.85    $23.64    $53.50    "+ Collection\n                                        In One Click\n                                    ~
 4 Charizard V #SWSH050 $8.00    $34.99    $79.98    "+ Collection\n                                        In One Click\n                                    ~
 5 Pikachu #24          $138.31  $362.72   $2,919.69 "+ Collection\n                                        In One Click\n                                    ~
 6 Entei #34            $8.50    $52.21    $153.63   "+ Collection\n                                        In One Click\n                                    ~
 7 Ancient Mew          $23.79   $99.99    $382.50   "+ Collection\n                                        In One Click\n                                    ~
 8 Charizard EX #XY121  $27.16   $135.00   $727.00   "+ Collection\n                                        In One Click\n                                    ~
 9 Mewtwo EX #XY107     $5.54    $77.50    $98.71    "+ Collection\n                                        In One Click\n                                    ~
10 Charizard GX #SM60   $28.57   $113.98   $492.00   "+ Collection\n                                        In One Click\n                                    ~
# ... with 878 more rows
```

Comment: Interesting how your code does not work on my computer. Specifically the `webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))` does not work, whereas, as my answer code specified, `remDr$executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")` seems to work. However, I rather like your loop approach to ensure that I get to the bottom of the page rather than my quick guess work. One thing to note. I believe there is an error in your solution where you accidentally wrote "click" that was not commented out.