# Access help for class method in R?

Tags: r

We can get help for any function like so `?dplyr::select`

How can we get help for a ***class method***, such as `remDr$findElement("css", "body")` (used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901072/scrolling-page-in-rselenium)). In aforementioned example, `findElement` is a method on an object of class `remoteDriver`

Note that we can look up the help docs online (e.g. at [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf) or github etc), but that's not what I'm after here - I would like the help inside of R (e.g. for offline use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R has several class systems. Use of the `$` operator seems to indicate that RSelenium uses the reference class system (can be confirmed by checking the [source code](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/search?q=setRefClass&unscoped_q=setRefClass)). The `remDr` object in the linked example is created by a call to the `remoteDriver` function and (as usual) the documentation of that function explains what calling it returns. There, the authors also explain the methods.

So, just use `help("remoteDriver")`.